# When booking through online travel websites, how do I know if the airline will treat multi-flights as separate trips or a single trip?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, transit, travel-agents

For example, this is one of the search result in Expedia for SIN-SFO flight in September:[image: Screenshot]

The proposed trip will have two flights, Singapore to Manila and Manila to SF. How do I know if the airline is going to treat it as separate trip or one trip? For me it will matter, for example,

- if I have to check in separately in Manila
- if the airline will move the baggage between the flights for me
- Since this is one short-haul flight and one long-haul flight, will my baggage allowance follow the long-haul allowance or the Singapore-Manila flight will have the short-haul allowance only.

Answer (score 3):

This will be treated as a single trip (leg), because you are actually booking a flight from SIN to SFO with one stop. So you can (and are expected) to check-in for both flights all the way to SFO.

If there would be two separate "boxes" with these two flights, then they would be treated as two separate legs in the booking.

Comment: you mean, I will need to check-in only once, I don't need to worry about moving my stuff in Manila, and I get the long-haul baggage allowance beginning from Singapore (not just during the Manila-San Francisco part)? Is this common knowledge or is there a place I can check this?

Comment: @Fitri, I guess it is common knowledge. You get the same kind of results when you book from the Airline's websites directly. To answer your questions (a) yes, you don't have to touch your stuff in Manila (b) your luggage allowance should be mentioned somewhere before you book (especially if it is different for the two legs). Usually it is the bigger one though.